# href link not clickable (appears to work in chrome inspect)

Tags: html, anchor

I hope you guys can help. I am currently doing an online course in HTML and CSS. As part of my course I am practising making webpages. I am having an issue with a header href.

I am trying to link from the header to a place in the body. However when I am testing on chrome it doesn't appear as a hyperlink. Using the inspect function of chrome shows it as a link and when clicked it works. However it doesnt work outside of inspect.

My HTML is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landing.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1>
        Heading
    </h1>
    <h2>Services <a href="#services_section"></a></h2>
    <div class="tag-line">
    </div>
</header>
<body>
<h3>
    About
</h3>
    <div class="about">     
<h4 id="services_section">
    <div class="services">
    Services
</h4>
<h5>
    <div class="contact">
    Contact
</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you mean to link on the "Services" text, use `<a href=...>Services</a>`. The current code shows the text "Services " and then a zero-space hyperlink after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperlink is working, the problem is that there is no text. You need to put your "Services" inside the  tag.

Change

```
<h2>Services <a href="#services_section"></a></h2>
```

to

```
<h2><a href="#services_section">Services</a></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that has solved the issue. That has helped me move on to the next step and continue my learning.